# Mongod Active: Failed (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Tags: mongodb

I am using ubuntu16.04 on VPS.
It has been migrated to another company's VPS and is in use.

nginix works fine and my node application works fine.

When the mongodb service is run as systemlctl stat
The following error code was shown and it became Active:Failed.

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-03-18 08:57:04 UTC; 3s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3558 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 3558 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Mar 18 08:57:04 user systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Mar 18 08:57:04 user systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Mar 18 08:57:04 user systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 18 08:57:04 user systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Below is my mongod.conf setting.

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

In my system

mongod.conf Path

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

mongodb DB path

```
/var/lib/mongodb
```

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know what I need to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably with the account mongo is trying to launch with in your systemd mongod.service file. Check the user and group defined in the [Service] block are valid.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm late in checking
It has already been settled
It was resolved by reinstalling the package.
I'll check what you told me later
Thank you for your reply